# Unicode in SMTP: any reason not to?

Tags: .net, email, unicode, encoding, smtp

I'd like to add Unicode characters to plain text email being sent via SMTP. Our implementation is based on .NET's System.Net.Mail, which makes it easy to specify Unicode encoding this way:

```
message.BodyEncoding =  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Even for English, switching to Unicode would allow me to include bullet points (Unicode code point U+2022 = •) in the email text. An alternate HTML email body permits using `<ul>` elements for bulleted lists, but for plain text email I'd like a solution that is less ugly than using asterixes or dashes for bullets.

Is there a downside to using Unicode encoding in SMTP? Should I worry that some recipients won't be able to receive or read the email due to this encoding?

Comment: You shouldn't worry about SMTP - it's a transport and will handle any content. Recipients - unless you are sending to some Unix junkies who are using command line email readers on a system not being updated to use Unicode - you are fine

Comment: By default, SMTP does not support transporting 8bit data, like UTF-8.  Either the SMTP server has to support 8BIT extensions to the SMTP protocol and the client has to request their use, or the email has to be encoded in a 7bit-friendly transport encoding instead, such as `base64` or `quoted-printable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several layers to this question, I believe.

First, the raw SMTP protocol does not handle UTF-8.  However, there are widely deployed extensions that add that support, and it should not be a problem as long as your code uses the correct magic.  The implementation you mention probably is good enough.

Second, if your UTF-8 message survives SMTP intact to the recipient, there is the question whether their mail client handles UTF-8 correctly.  Basic support is, I believe, widely deployed, but some older clients may have a problem.  Problems may ensue if you use exotic characters, as the recipient may not have correct fonts.  However, any client that handles HTML email is likely to handle UTF-8 as well.

If you know your likely recipients, I'd recommend testing with their setups.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any mail client that don't support Unicode nowadays. Anyway, a short test would be preferable (at least, ask your clients which mail client do they use). A downside of having increased message size doesn't count, unless you are going to have unusually huge messages.

(A note aside: I am quite used to asterisks in plain text mail messages, are they really so ugly?)